# In the MVC paradigm, Is the View init in the Controller or is the Controller init in the View?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Basically in my card game I'm having trouble with action listeners and the communication/ cohesion between the Controller and viewer class. I don't really understand how to connect them. Because I am beyond the actual learning of java, I am really trying to learn about the structure of java and how to efficiently and professionally produce a program such as a game.

Here's what I have of my code so far. I'm making phase 10.

```
public class Game {

private ArrayList<Player> players;
private Deck playDeck;
private ArrayList<Set> table;
private View view;


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.run();
}

public void run() {
    initPlayers(1);
    initView();
    createDeck();
        for(Player player: players){
            player.setDrawn(false);
           while(!player.hasDrawn()){
               if(*player clicks deck to draw card*){
                  Card topCard = playDeck.getTopCard();
                  player.addCard(topCard);
                  view.createCardComponent();
                  player.setDrawn(true);
               }


public class View implements MouseListener{
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel handPanel;
    JPanel deckPanel;
    public View()
    {
    }

    public void makeFrame()
    {
       frame = new JFrame("Phase 10");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       handPanel = new JPanel();
       deckPanel = new JPanel();
       handPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       frame.add(handPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
       frame.add(deckPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
       deckPanel.add(new DeckDisplay());
       frame.pack();
       frame.setSize(1000,500);
       frame.setResizable(true);
       frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       frame.setVisible(true);

    public void createCardComponent(){
        CardDisplay card = new CardDisplay();
        handPanel.add(card);
        card.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void update(){
        handPanel.revalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {

        }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Guillaume Polet.

But I would even say, that use should make a launcher class that *creates objects* and then /*wires them up together.*

If you create your views in your controller you have a pretty tight coupling of components.
If you operate on abstract interfaces (in any programming language) and provide implementation at run time you gain a lot of flexibility. You can then move your configuration to external files (i.e. XML) and load it as config.

Answer (score 0):

Controller instantiates views.

As for your code, I don't really understand what you are looking for an answer. Your code is incomplete and I don't really see an MVC pattern. The model should be your Deck and cards. DeckDisplay and CardDisplay are your views. Your controller tied them all together. You should probably split those classes into separate files.

Comment: I just copy and pasted my view and controller class. Game being the controller and view being the view. Only gui objects are in the view and my logic in the game class. The deck and card classes in the game are a separate class then the cardDisplay and deckDisplay classes. I was showing in my game class that i initialized a view object in the game class and then where my code tries to see if until the player draws a card he can only draw a card. The problem is How does the controller see if the player clicked on the deck object from the view if the view holds the listeners.